# The interpretation of a graph that is constructed using $\sin(x!)$

Tags: functions

> I wanted to know the interpretation of a graph that is constructed using
> $$f(x) = \sin(x!)$$

[image]

$\sin(x!)$ : the plot of graph at $(170.65,0.633)$ ends

Comment: The "end" of the graph is only an artifact of the computation capabilities of Desmos. $170!$ is $>10^{306}$.

Comment: @user3733558 You mean due to limitation of Desmos , we dont get the further charting beyond the point  (170.65,0.633) ?

Comment: Exactly.Well, it's not really Demos' fault, it's our computers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: i am using the following charting tool https://www.transum.org/Maths/Activity/Graph/Desmos.asp  , do you suggest a better or more advanced version of Desmos which i should be using

Comment: No matter what graphing tool you want to use, you will hit the numerical limit of the computer, rather sooner than later. So, no, I don't have a suggestion. Just don't forget that computers have (finite) limits.

Comment: The precision of the graph is of course limited by the size of the pixels (of course we can work around this issue with a zoom-function). Desmos has limits in its calculation precisions , but only because it is not designed for higher precisions.

Comment: $x!$ quickly increases and calculating the sine of large values needs high precision. But there are tools that can do that easily, so it is a matter of the software, not of the computers. PARI/GP is not bad, but MATHEMATICA is surely much more powerful.

Comment: @RajeshChaurasia What do you want to know **exactly** about $\sin(x!)$? Have you seen that there are issues at negative integers?

Comment: For negative values of x the sin(x!) quickly reduces the value of function to 0 and it doesnot change for smaller and smaller values of x ( -ve of huge number denoted to be -x!).The graph interests me and i wanted to know its behaviour which part of it is already explained by others here.

Comment: @RajeshChaurasia Do you know what $x!$ *means* when $x$ is not a positive integer?

Comment: @Joe The factorials of real negative numbers, are complex numbers .The factorials of real negative integers have their imaginary part equal to zero and hence are real nos.

Answer (score 1):

The graph of $\sin(x!)$ has a root whenever $x!$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$. Because $x!$ is convex, the spacing between the roots of $\sin(x!)$ approaches $0$ as $x$ tends to infinity. This explains the oscillatory behaviour of the graph. Eventually, the computer can't handle it, not only because $x!$ becomes extremely large, but because the lines on the graph gets so close to each other that the thickness of the lines make it look as if there is a solid block of colour.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the sin(x!) graph

Comment: @RajeshChaurasia: No problem. If you have any questions regarding my answer, then feel free to ask.